# Jquery - get from html attribute a callback name in event delegation

Tags: jquery

I have a table with many records.
To improve perfomence I use the jquery event delegation.

```
<div id="table">
  <div class="dosomething" uid="1">first</div>
  <div class="dosomething" uid="2">second</div>
  ..etc
</div>  

$('#table').on('click', '.dosomething', function() {
  var htmlMsg = 'foo bar';
  var uid = $(this).attr('uid');
  // Now call confirm Dialog
  callDialog(htmlMsg, uid, changeCrt);
});

function callDialog(htmlMsg, uid, callback) {
  $('#confirm').dialog({
   resizable: false,
   autoOpen: false,
   modal: true,
   buttons:
   {
      Yes: function ()
      {
          $(this).dialog("close");
          callback(uid);
      },
      No: function ()
      {
          $(this).dialog("close");
      }
   }
}).html(htmlMsg).dialog('open');
}

function changeCrt(uid) {
   do something
}
```

To be able to use for most scenarios I would like to pass the callback name dynamically passed via html attribute.
I tried in this way

```
<div id="table">
      <div class="dosomething" uid="1" act="changeCrt">first</div>
      <div class="dosomething" uid="2" act="changeCrt">second</div>
      ..etc
</div>

$('#table').on('click', '.dosomething', function() {
    var htmlMsg = 'foo bar';
    var uid = $(this).attr('uid');
    var act = $(this).attr('act');
    // Now call confirm Dialog
    callDialog(htmlMsg, uid, act);
});
```

but I get this error from the console

**TypeError: callback is not a function.**

how can I fix it? thanks

Comment: whether the callback method is specified in a dom ready callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to call the function using square bracket notation, using the scope in which you defined the function, which in this case, is `window`:

```
Yes: function ()
{
    $(this).dialog("close");
    window[callback](uid);
},
```

Or, if you don't want to pollute window's namespace, create a library object to keep your callback:

```
var library = {
    changeCrt: function(uid) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

And use your library as the scope:

```
Yes: function ()
{
    $(this).dialog("close");
    library[callback](uid);
},
```

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing changes. TypeError: [callback] is not a function.

Comment: Which must mean that your callback function is in a different scope. You need to find out this scope.

Comment: If I set manually the name of callback function - callDialog(htmlMsg, uid, changeCrt), all is ok, but if I get the name of callback from the attr, it return the error message

Comment: That's because you are passing changeCrt as an identifier, not a string.

Comment: Ok and how do I pass it as identifier taking it from an attribute? thanks

Comment: Just like I have shown you above (: -- I.E it would look something like `window["changeCrt"]()` -- But you need to know the scope in which it is defined.

Comment: I think I will leave this way at the moment. Thanks for your help

Comment: @ George - You could see my answer and tell me what you think? thanks

Comment: A solution to what? Your switch statement doesn't really do much. Also, please don't use the answer box to reply. If you have another question, ask another question (:

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a good solution?

```
  var act = $(this).attr('act');

  switch (act)
  {
     case "changeCrt":
        callDialog(htmlMsg, uid, changeCrt);
     break;

  }
```

Thank you for your suggestion.